# Words that are pluralized in the middle?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, suffixes, compounds, inflectional-morphology

This is purely a curiosity, but I'm fascinated by mid-word pluralization, even if the word in question is a compound word.

For example, **passersby** or **standersby**.

No others have occurred to me. Can you provide other examples, or a link to a resource that enumerates them?

I'm particularly interested in compounds that do not include spaces or hyphens.

Comment: Hmm, haven't seen "standersby" before, only "bystanders" (usually as in "innocent bystanders"; though, as every copper knows, nobody is innocent ;-)

Comment: Especially bypassers, these guys always plot something sinister ;)

Comment: [William Safire Orders Two Whoppers Junior](http://www.theonion.com/articles/william-safire-orders-two-whoppers-junior,3351/)

Comment: @Rob Perfection.

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard That's exactly the mentality of why I get nervous around cops

Comment: Goose and Geese make a horrible example.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It could be any compound noun of which the *head*, the "main noun", is not the final part of the compound. This includes all compound nouns whose final parts are not nouns. "Bystanders" is normally not written as you did. In "passers-by", the final part is "by", which is not a noun. Note that there might be some controversy about the correct spelling of some such words, but I just try to be consistent. A few examples:

- runners-up
- fins-de-siècle (and many more French words)
- houses of cards
- Commanders-in-Chief
- sons-in-law
- attorneys at law
- (tea)spoonsful
- ...

Comment: And also *-in-law* words.

Comment: @Jimi: Right! I will add that.

Comment: Except for the word *in-law* itself, oddly :)

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Hey I never realized that. I suppose no other choice was left when the head got dropped. Still, an amusing plural. Cf. syntax-less compounds like "drop-outs" — or is there some syntax? Is it a phrase noun (or what are those called)?

Comment: And let's not forget attorneys at law. Hmm, on second thought, maybe we should just forget them.

Comment: @Robusto: Hey, are they evil? Some of my best friends...

Comment: I wonder if *database* counts as one of these.

Comment: This wikipedia article has a lot of examples of this kind if you scroll down to the seventh subhead (Plurals of compound nouns): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plural

Comment: Also, [tea]spoonful/[tea]spoonsful, etc., where both forms of the plural exist.

Comment: Gah! So many exceptions in this language! This form of pluralization always bothered me, but then again, I am a rather persnickety individual!

Comment: @LucasTizma: Well, this does have its own rule: it happens with compound nouns whose final part is not a noun. But, yeah, it does tend to look odd in a way.

Comment: @Cerberus Right, well, it's good to know that there are rules established for things like this. That's some comfort!

Comment: Sergeants-major has always been my favorite,

Answer (score 8):

**Men-o’-war** is a nice one: shows that irregular plurals are just as susceptible to this construction.

Also:  **pickers-up**, on the same pattern as **passers-by**.

Answer (score 7):

- [courts-martial](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/court_martial)
- [men-at-arms](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/men-at-arms)

And a few more [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plural#Plurals_of_compound_nouns):

- bills of attainder
- directors general
- fees simple absolute
- ships of the line
- ministers-president
- knights-errant
- procurators fiscal

Answer (score 4):

Besides those in others' answers, there are: *attorneys general*, *secretaries general*, *solicitors general*, *postmasters general*, *governors-general*, etc.; *[noun]s-elect*; and *Knights Templar* and *Knights Hospitaller*.

Comment: Though I would argue that all the 'general' compounds - eve "governer-general" are in process of changing to a regular plural.

Comment: Polite disagreement here; "attorneys general" is going strong and reinforcing the rule.

Answer (score 3):

Another example is *culs-de-sac*, the plural of *cul-de-sac*.

Comment: Cul-de-sacs is also an accepted plural.http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cul-de-sac