# What is the plural of proof of concept? Is it proofs of concept, proof of concepts or proofs of concepts?

Tags: grammatical-number

Can someone please clarify what is the plural form of proof of concept? Is it proofs of concept, proof of concepts or proofs of concepts?

Comment: I would simply say `POCs`.. Most people use the abbreviated form in conversations.. to say the whole thing is so tiring..

Comment: While writing formally `proof-of-concept's` could be used I guess..

Comment: It might depend on you have many different proofs of one concept, or many different proofs of many different concepts.

Comment: @userSeven7s no. That is so wrong I don't know where to start.

Comment: @userSeven7s proof-of-concept's *what*?

Comment: I am closing this as general reference, since [Wiktionary has the answer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proof_of_concept). See also: [Words that are pluralized in the middle](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8450/words-that-are-pluralized-in-the-middle).

Answer (score 18):

It's *proofs of concept*.

As the moderator's closure comment indicates, the [Wiktionary:Talk](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk%3aproof_of_concept) page is a good reference; e.g. compare to "mothers-in-law" or "attorneys-at-law."

Comment: What if I have multiple proofs of multiple concepts? as @FrustratedWithForms. said..

Comment: Then you would have *multiple* proofs of concept, *not* "proofs of concepts"

Comment: @Ronnie your question seems inadvertently redundant. Proof of concept is one proof for one general concept. Proofs of concept are multiple proofs for one general concept. "Proofs of concept" is a grouping; so multiple groups would just be as _ish_ said, multiple proofs of concept. While each concept can have multiple proofs, it is unlikely that one proof will apply to discrete concepts. As it is already a grouping, saying _multiple_ doesn't really change its plurality. I get what you're trying to say, but you're sort of inventing a novel problem that doesn't really need to be further solved.

Answer (score 5):

If you consider *proof of concept* a compound phrase, it would be *proofs of concept*. In *The Associated Press Stylebook*, it says for compound words that involve separate words or words linked by a hyphen, make the most significant word plural:

> - Significant word first: *adjutants general, aides-de-camp, attorneys general, courts-martial, daughters-in-law, passers-by, postmasters general, presidents-elect, secretaries general, sergeants major*
> - Significant word in the middle: *assistant attorneys general, deputy chiefs of staff*
> - Significant word last: *assistant attorneys, assistant corporation counsels, deputy sheriffs, lieutenant colonels, major generals*

Comment: I've always wondered whether *cul-de-sac* happens to follow this rule.

Comment: Per my *American Heritage Dictionary*, 4th ed., it can be either *culs-de-sac* or *cul-de-sacs*. I would guess in U.S. suburbia, that *cul-de-sacs* is more commonly used.

Comment: Stating the rule in terms of "most significant word" seems unnecessarily ambiguous to me. I learned it as "make the noun plural, not any adjective or other modifiers". So, for example, a "court martial" is a court that is martial (i.e. related to the military), not a martial that is court. So to make it plural, we say "courts martial", because there are two courts, not two "martials". Granted it can be confusing because in some cases a word can be both a noun and an adjective, but we have to look at how it's used in this particular phrase. ...

Comment: ... Like "attorney general". Yes, "general" can be a noun, as in the military rank. But here it's being used as an adjective. The "attorney" has "general" authority.