# How to pluralize "Air de cour"?

Tags: grammatical-number, loanwords

An *air de cour* is a type of Baroque song. If I’m talking about several of these, would I say “we played some *airs de cour*”?

Frankly, and especially since this is a foreign phrase (French), the thing that seems most natural to me in speaking it aloud is actually to say “*air de cours*”.

I realize this is not correct in French speech, but in English, it wouldn’t sound right at all to say “*airs de cour*”, particularly since the “*de cour*” means nothing to most saxophones.

Of course, I would never say “I bought some *jar of chocolates*”, but that’s because the “*of chocolates*” means something in English, so it would sound wrong and be wrong.

It seems to me that in pluralizing a foreign noun phrase, it may as well be treated as a single word when spoken aloud, with the *s* added at the end.

Is there a rule on this?

Comment: Have a look at this question about [words that are pluralized in the middle](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8450/words-that-are-pluralized-in-the-middle).

Comment: Don’t use a foreign phrase if you don’t want to give it the *aides-de-campy* treatment.

Comment: Since *air* is a perfectly good English noun that in this phrase means the same in English and in French, I think *airs de cour* is the right plural.

Comment: I’m guessing that *any* wording you choose is going to mean nothing to most saxophones.

Comment: [This section of the Wikipedia article on English plurals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plural#Plurals_of_compound_nouns) seems quite good on the subject.

Comment: I think it's General Reference. Wikipedia's article on this (admittedly obscure) term says *The first use of the term 'air de cour' was in Adrian Le Roy's '**Airs** de cour miz sur le luth'*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: but that seems to be in a different language...

Comment: @sumelic: True, that actual *title* is French. But the Wikipedia article, which is only five paragraphs long, subsequently uses the plural form *seven times* within its English text.

Comment: Definitely go with "airs de cour." Your target audience, if they can understand the word in the first place, is gonna know it's right (and if they can't, it doesn't matter)