# Why are certain single word compound nouns pluralized in the middle

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, compounds

*Hypothesis:* compound nouns that are unhyphenated single words can be pluralized by adding an “s” to the noun root *only* when they consist of a noun + preposition.

This is a follow-up to an [earlier question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8450/words-that-are-pluralized-in-the-middle)

Numerous examples are given in the Answers to that Question listing compound nouns that pluralize in the middle by adding an “s” to the *head* or *root* noun, such as **sons-in-law** and **secretaries general**.

However, other than **passersby**, (the word posed in the question and the word that got me thinking, before I found that question), and **standersby** (for which I cannot find an online definition), all of the examples in that Q&A, and those that I can think of or find, are either hyphenated or written as an unhyphenated noun phrase.

Virtually all of these spaced or hyphenated examples are either *noun + adjective* or *noun + prepositional phrase*.  The only exception in the examples from the earlier Question is **[spoonsful](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/spoonful)**, but this seems to be a less favored variant of **spoonfuls** (although Microsoft considers *spoonfuls* incorrect and *spoonsful* correct).

There are other single word, unhyphenated compound constructions that serve as nouns which consist of a verb form + preposition which pluralize the usual way, such as

> shutouts
>
> takeovers
>
> flybys

Is it possible that the reason for the **passersby** type construction (plural noun root, no space, no hyphen) is the particular combination of noun + preposition?  This appears to be a rather rare construction.

I have reviewed word lists in [onelook.com](http://onelook.com/) for any construction with a [word]+s+preposition by searching *sby and other *s[preposition] combinations.  (I could not search *s+in because of the volume.)

The only other examples I have found are **strikesthrough** and **sneaksby**.  The only reference to **strikesthrough** is a [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/strikesthrough) entry which considers the overall word to be a verb, but several of the listed cites appear to be typos.  **Sneaksby** is actually a singular form.

One or two examples are a poor way to make a rule, but could it be that this particular plural form is limited to this particular parts-of-speech structure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In English there's no such thing as a plural form for an adjective or a preposition. So if you have a compound noun, like "court martial", to make it plural you should pluralize the noun and not the adjective. Hence, "courts martial". There aren't two martials; there are two courts.

Similarly, "passersby" make sense because there are two "passers", not two "byes". "Two spoonsful" because there are two spoons that are full, not two fulls that are spoon. Etc.

But "flyby" is in a different category. It is a noun formed by combining a verb and a preposition. There are not two "byes", but neither are there two "flies". Similarly with "takeover" and "shutout". There is no "inner noun" in these cases to pluralize. So it is the combined word as a whole that is a noun, and it makes sense to pluralize it as a whole word and not as a compound.

Comment: Grands Prix is an accepted form of the plural of Grand Prix in English as well as French. Blond / blonde is possibly the only English adjectival lexeme which inflects for gender.

Comment: 'courts martial' referes to multiple courts, but 'courtmartials' refers to multiple courtmartial acts, so both plurals seem ok to me.

Comment: @Gaston I've never seen that usage of "courtmartial". Do you have a reference?

Comment: A quick google search shows a number of examples, mostly being cases of multiple people being courtmartialled in the one court (-martial): the [Bounty](http://www.fatefulvoyage.com/trial/trialHome.html); some [Marines](http://articles.cnn.com/2011-10-27/justice/justice_us-marines-hazing_1_harry-lew-body-armor-suicide-note?_s=PM:JUSTICE); [military law](http://www.militarylawyers.org/court-martial-levels-difference.php).

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut I meant a reference explicitly stating that this is how the term is used. Many people pluralize "court-martial" as "court-martials", but I have always taken it that they were just making a mistake.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What about brunet/brunette?

Comment: "Courtmartial" has probably been so thoroughly assimilated by now that nobody recognizes it as a 'martial' court. Note the closed spelling -- although to be sure, when this happened to (Captain- and) Lieutenant- and Major-General, the hyphen was dropped and the spelling was opened up.

Comment: @StoneyB You get back to the issue we've discussed on this forum many times that ultimately "correct language" is defined by the concensus of what everybody says and writes. But I cling to the idea that some changes in usage should be resisted as illogical or inconsistent. (Other changes should be embraced as enhancing logic and consistency.) Okay, this isn't one I'd put up a big fight over.

Comment: I don't think an analogy to levels of general is valid, because a major-general is not a kind of major, but a kind of general. BTW, in the US, at least, there is no such thing as a "captain-general". Maybe that's a rank in some other country's military.

Comment: @Jay  *Originally*, in the 16th Century, the officer placed over several Captains (then the ordinary term for the leader of an army) was a "Captain General" - a Captain with "general" or overall command. Eventually a Lieutenant and Major were similarly promoted to assist him: a "Lieutenant General" commanding all units of horse and a "Major General" commanding all units of foot. Subsequently they came to be regarded as grades of "General Officer", as you now understand it.

Comment: "Court martial" is not a compound noun. Like "secretary general", it is a rare example in English of the adjective being placed after the noun.

Comment: "Spoonfuls" is correct. The argument here in favour of "spoonsful" is invalid: there are no spoons, full or otherwise. "Spoonful" does not mean "full spoon"; it means an amount enough to fill a spoon. We may talk of such an amount in the plural. In that case, as with your examples "flyby" etc., it is the combined word as a whole that is a noun and gets pluralised.

Answer (score 4):

According to *Warriner's English Grammar and Composition* (1977), most plurals of compound nouns are formed in accordance with two rules. First:

> **The plural of compound nouns written as one word is formed by adding *s* or *es*.**
>
> EXAMPLES: *spoonfuls*, *cupfuls*, *leftovers*, *strongboxes*

Second:

> **The plural of compound nouns consisting of a noun plus a modifier is formed by making the modified word plural.**
>
> To determine the word that is modified in a compound word, make each of the parts plural. The modified word is the one that tells what the entire compound is or does. Thus the plural of *notary public* is *notaries public* (they are *notaries* not *publics*); the plural of *mother-in-law* is *mothers-in-law* (they are *mothers*, not *laws*); etc.
>
> EXAMPLES: *runners-up*, *editors in chief*, *lieutenant governors*, *poets laureate*

However, this book does note some exceptions:

> **The plural of a few compound nouns is formed in irregular ways.**
>
> EXAMPLES: *drive-ins*, *stand-bys*, *six-year-olds*, *tie-ups*

At least in the examples that *Warriner's* gives, all of the exceptions involve hyphenated compounds. *The Chicago Manual of Style* and *Words Into Type* concur with *Warriner's* on the general rules, but they don't address the exceptions.

Of course, as language marches on, hyphenated forms sometimes become closed-up forms, with the result that a plural that used to follow the *Warriner's* rule (like *passers-by*) suddenly becomes an exception to the rule (*passersby*). In the instance that bib asks about, a look at dictionaries in Merriam-Webster's *Collegiate Dictionary* series reveals that MW listed *passers-by* as the primary spelling up through the *Sixth Collegiate Dictionary* (1943), but that *passersby* took over in the *Seventh Collegiate* (1963) and has remained MW's primary spelling ever since.