# Recipe — "spoonfuls" seems right but it seems wrong too

Tags: grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are certain single word compound nouns pluralized in the middle](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79838/why-are-certain-single-word-compound-nouns-pluralized-in-the-middle)

> Drop by spoonfuls, 2 inches apart, onto a greased baking sheet.

*Spoonful* or *spoonsful*? Seems it should be *spoonful* as there is only one spoon and one dollop of dough.  But it sounds wrong to my ear.  Maybe it is just misused too much in recipes.

Comment: @tylerharms No, that is ***not*** an “explanation” at your link. It is merely a rule, and tells you nothing more about the matter than that one should form noun plurals of *<container>+ful* words by adding a final *s*.  It does not say ***why*** one does so, as an explanation would necessarily explain.

Comment: @tchrist: Thank you for the clarification. After reading your answer and doing further research, I am going to delete the comment because there just seems to be too much ambiguity with this expression to focus on the rule.

Comment: @Robusto, et al, please explain to me how this  is a duplicate to why we say "Secretaries General?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the operation requires more than one spoonful, writers need not avoid *spoonfuls*. The plural of *spoonful* was once *spoonsful*, but *spoonfuls* seems to be the preferred form now.

Answer (score 10):

According to the OED, the plural of ***spoonful*** is today always simply ***spoonfuls***, and indeed, has usually been so historically as well:

> - 1625 Laws *Stannaries* iii. (1808) 17 ― A true note in writing··certifying the just number of pieces, slabs, or spoonfuls of tin above a pound weight.
> - 1652 N. Culverwel *Lt. Nature* ɪ. xv. (1661) 127 ― Babes in Intellectuals must take in··those spoonfuls of Knowledge.
> - 1800 tr. *Lagrange’s Chem.* I. 430 ― Throw this mixture by spoonfuls into a crucible.

The other nouns that end in *‑ful* work this way too, even the ones dealing with measurements like *armful* and *quartful*, *capful* and *cupful*, *ladleful* and *lapful*.

That said, there have been exceptions to this in the historical record, including a few within living memory. For example, listed under the β (beta) forms for ***spoonful***, the OED does have some examples of writing its plural ***spoonsful*** (in various spellings), but most of these are really quite old:

> - 1527 Andrew *Brunswyke’s Distyll. Waters* D j, ― Dronke of the same water foure spones full at nyght is good agaynste the hote cowgh.
> - 1599 A. M. tr. *Gabelhouer’s Bk. Physicke* 145/2 ― Administre of this water thre spoonesfulle.
> - 1863 Bates *Nat. Amazon* v. (1864) 125 ― We had brought with us a bag of farinha,··and a few spoonsful of salt.
> - 1897 Ouida *Massarenes* xiii, ― Two spoonsful of Cognac in it.

Another historical exception I found in the OED is an irregular ***boatsful*** version, from the 17<sup>th</sup> century:

> - 1652 *Season Exp. Netherl.* 9 ― Loaden by Boats full.
> - 1873 Symonds *Grk. Poets* ix. 289 ― A boatful of careless persons.
> - 1883 *Contemp. Rev.* June 851 ― Whole boatfuls of women.

The OED entry for **handful** contains an interesting note in its etymology section, which suggests an answer to why things have gone as they have:

> **Etymology**: OE. *handfull* str. fem., plur. *handfulla*, f. *hand* + *full* adj.: cf. ONor. *handfyllr*, Ger. *handvoll*. 
> Though composed, like *mouthful*, of sb. and adj., the compound was in OE. and ME. a true sb., inflected as a whole; hence its plural is properly *handfuls*, not *handsful*.

Curiously, an irregular plural *bucketsful* does appear to have some mild currency. The earliest citation almost looks like a place we might today use suspension hyphens:

> - 1656 Trapp *Comm. Matt.* vii. 11 ― He will pour out··as it were by pails or buckets fuls.
> - 1843 *Spirit of Times* 30 Sept. 366/3 ― The rain··came pouring down in buckets-full.
> - 1892 C. M. Yonge *That Stick* II. xxxviii. 181 ― She cried bucketsful. 
>     1936 W. R. Titterton *G. K. Chesterton* ii. iv. 145 ― Turning out books in buckets-full.

Another counterexample provided is under ***saucepanful***:

> - 1976 *Horse & Hound* 3 Dec. 34/4 ― Two or three saucepansful may be needed simultaneously and it is a good idea to put a spoon in the glass when dispensing.

On the other hand, it is always ***pursefuls***:

> - 1846 Mrs. Gore *Sk. Eng. Char.* (1852) 7 ― The unthrifty, who had flung about pursefulls of those bits of tin, began to hoard the new issue of the mint, as having more significance.