# Is it "invoice receivables" or "invoices receivable"?

Tags: grammatical-number, compound-adjectives

The latter follows the analogy of accounts receivable as a post-positive adjective.

Comment: Related: [Words that are pluralized in the middle?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8450/words-that-are-pluralized-in-the-middle)

Answer (score 2):

English adjectives do not inflect for number<sup>1</sup>; nouns do (although some nouns have the same singular and plural forms).

Thus post-positive adjectives behave in the same way as those which go before the noun: the noun is pluralised and the adjective is not.

> - accounts receivable
> - courts martial
> - Attorneys-General

<sup>1</sup> Adjectives which are loanwords from another language **may** inflect for number in the same way as their source language.

Comment: Correct as it goes. However, note that this "rule" is not always observed in the USA. Many assert that is a mistake (particularly English teachers), but if so it is a prevalent one, so don't be suprised if you encounter it.

Comment: This question is related to accounting and there is a different treatment of the noun in that case, and invoice becomes a verb/adjective designate. Invoiced Receivables is plural because there are many designations under the category of Receivables, including interest, fees, payment in lieu of, financed, stock value, pending receipt, invoiced, non-invoiced, in transit, etcetera.

Comment: @Cindy; *Receivables* is always a noun, though it is indeed backformed from 'items receivable' where *receivable* is an adjective.

Comment: Also accounts payable

Comment: Thanks for the great explanations fellow StackExchange members.     As it stands, I think there are two ways to treat "invoice(s) receivable(s)": 1. as a noun phrase that contains a post-positive adjective (receivable) 2. as a noun phrase where invoice although by its form is a noun, is doing the work of an adjective in terms of its position and function within the NP as well as when used in a sentence and therefore allows for receivable (a very well established noun the in financial industry) to take the plural.

Comment: My feeling is that #2 is right. I can't make sense of invoices receivable as a stand-alone NP. The only way it makes sense for "invoices receivable" is when we try to use a short form in place of an entire sentence: Those invoices [are] receivable in 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is **Invoiced receivables** as opposed to receivables that are pending in the system for which invoice numbers have not been assigned. This might occur at a law office where an accountant enters information that can be charged to the client or will not be charged to the client. Pro bono work is not invoiced, yet it is hours expended and incurs expenses.