# Are there words similar to 'passersby'?

Tags: exceptions

The plural of 'passerby' is 'passer**s**by' with an 's' acting like an infix (W-B says that this is the *only* plural form of the  word). This seems like a very interesting exception, so I thought I would ask a question.

Are there any other English words that are made plural by an 's' put *inside* the noun?

One criterion has to be met: the singular noun is composed of one (unhyphenated) word only.

Comment: Yes, e.g. [governors-general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Governor-general). For single-word nouns, consider [basketsful](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/basketsful), though ODO renders it [basketfuls](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/basket?q=basketful#basket__13).

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, edited the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/8450/42179

Comment: @Keepthesemind a duplicate, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

It's a classic example of a compound noun where the noun is first. In compound nouns the head is often pluralized. Generally compound word plurals are often arbitrary. Yay!

Have a look at this [blog from Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/grammatik/britisch-grammatik/nouns-compound-nouns)

[Sister**s**-in-law](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sister%20in%20law)

Brother**s**-in-law

Thank**s**giving

The table of changing plurals over  [here](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-compound-plural.htm) suggests that the 's' tends to move to the end over time. It lists the same **bucketsful** Lawrence mentions in the comments with the *new style plural* **bucketfuls**.

EDIT: Dang, you can't just make up more rules ;) But Sister-in-law holds up.

Comment: The number of rules has diminished by one, but the question has turned out to be a duplicate. Thank you for your time and have a good one :)