# Presidents Elect or President-Elects?

Tags: grammatical-number, compounds, postpositive

If you have several presidents awaiting inauguration, should we refer to them as Presidents Elect or President-Elects?

Comment: This is one of those weird cases of using Latin word order. True English would be Elect President, and obviously the plural Elect Presidents.  So following that, put the s on President: Presidents Elect.

Comment: @developerwjk Or French, really, since that's how that pattern got into English — and why you often see it in contexts of official authority like Surgeons General, Postmasters General, courts martial, and attorneys at law. Norman conquest and all that.

Comment: Please show research you have carried out. It may be found to be inconclusive, but reasonable research is expected on ELU.

Comment: **Presidents-Elect**. It is a postpositive adjective. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective

Comment: It's incomprehensible to me how any question of a hyphen arose there.

*Presidents elect* is correct in this case, and if there were an alternative it would surely be *preseident elects* and never *president-elects* - and there isn't.

I also don't understand how anyone could think any of this idiosyncratic.

Answer (score 19):

**Presidents-elect**.  Pluralize the noun.

cf. [Words that are pluralized in the middle?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8450/words-that-are-pluralized-in-the-middle)

see [AP Stylebook](http://www.mtcra.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/PLURALS-AND-POSSESSIVES.pdf):

> - **Significant word first:**  adjutants general, aides-de-camp, attorneys general, courts-martial, daughters-in-law, passers-by,
>     postmasters general, **presidents-elect,** secretaries-general,
>     sergeants major.
> - Significant word in the middle: assistant attorneys
>     general, deputy chiefs of staff.
> - Significant word last: assistant
>     attorneys, assistant corporation counsels, deputy sheriffs, lieutenant
>     colonels, major generals.

**Addendum:**

Language obviously changes over time.  At the moment, traditionalists like AP Style prefer to pluralize **president-elect** as **presidents-elect**.  Other arbiters of acceptable usage, e.g. [Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/president%20elect) and reputable organizations like [CBS News,](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/donald-trump-president-obama-3-things-noticeably-absent-from-first-meeting-at-white-house/) [ABC News](http://abcnews.go.com/Politics/donald-trump-spend-inauguration-eve/story?id=44621457) and [Pew Research Center](http://www.people-press.org/2016/12/08/1-views-of-president-elect-trump-and-his-administration/) consider **president-elects** the proper pluralization.

The [U.S. Senate's website devoted to the presidential inaugural ceremonies](https://www.inaugural.senate.gov/days-events/morning-worship-service/) pluralizes both ways on the same web page.  This gives a very clear example that usage is in flux. See the two examples below.  The differing pluralizations follow directly one after the other without any intervening text.

> The following list provides information on Inauguration Day worship
>   services attended by Presidents and **Presidents-elect** since 1933.
>
> WORSHIP SERVICES ATTENDED BY **PRESIDENT-ELECTS**

Comment: This seems like a construct that's so rarely needed that there's not enough tradition to produce a consensus.

Comment: @Barmar But is this not informed by whether you say, as I would, "attorneys-general", and "brothers-in-law", or whether you would say "attorney-generals" etc.

Comment: @WS2 As I understand it, these are all ideosyncratic, you can't generalize. AP Style has apparently assumed that they should follow the same convention, Merriam-Webster differs.

Comment: @KRyan, thanks for the edit.  You cleaned things up nicely and have given me a good model for a more concise post.

Comment: @choster et al., I have finally incorporated your helpful comments into my answer.  It was very interesting to find "presidents-elect" and "president-elects" right next to each other on the Senate's webpage about the inauguration. I'm not sure whether you noticed.

Answer (score 7):

Preferably, the same way you would write the singular noun (which can vary according to style), but with the head noun pluralized. So if you write President-elect, the plural is Presidents-elect; if you write President elect then Presidents elect.

For whatever it matters, the [Presidential Transition Act of 1963](https://www.gsa.gov/portal/content/178083) uses the terms "President-elect", "Vice President-elect", "Presidents-elect", and "Vice Presidents-elect". The [20th Amendment](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution/amendmentxx), on the other hand, uses the terms "President elect" and "Vice President elect" and makes no use of the plurals.

"President-elects" is valid in the sense that you can tack an -s onto any English noun and generally be understood, but it has a great deal of tradition working against it. "President elects", without the hyphen, also has the disadvantage of being confusable with President (singular noun) elects (verb).

Comment: Nice find on the PTA of '63! It's definitely a citation worth noting for this question.